# SQL Script converted to MySQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql, code-translation

I am trying to fix this migration history problem but can't get this to work in MySQL

```
SELECT *
INTO [TempMigrationHistory]
FROM [__MigrationHistory]

DROP TABLE [__MigrationHistory]

EXEC sp_rename 'TempMigrationHistory', '__MigrationHistory'
```

How would I get this working in mySQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A close equivalent mysql SQL for the SQL Server t-sql provided is something like what follows here.  (Obviously field1, field2 are placeholders.)

```
CREATE TABLE `TempMigrationHistory` LIKE `__MigrationHistory`;

INSERT INTO `TempMigrationHistory` (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2
FROM `__MigrationHistory`;

DROP TABLE `__MigrationHistory`;

RENAME TABLE `TempMigrationHistory` to `__MigrationHistory`;
```

Points to note...

- [mysql does not support SELECT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) but it does have the [CREATE TABLE LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) statement that SQL Server does not.
- Backticks (`) are used by convention in mysql instead of square brackets ([) in t-sql.
- mysql often has special system commands that take the place of SQL Server system stored procedure functionality (like sp_rename with [RENAME TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html) in this case).

At the end of this sequence of operations it seems you have exactly what you started with so I'm a bit confused about the desire to execute this sequence of events, but I suppose that's a tangent to your question.

Comment: I thought there was also `CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT ...` in MySQL, which would be closer to T-SQL's `SELECT INTO` than `CREATE TABLE LIKE` + `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Comment: @Adriy: good point about `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`.  It would be another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not all RDBMS's behave the same. Have you considered searching for the MySQL syntax for creating an [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement? E.g.,

```
INSERT INTO TempMigrationHistory
            (Col1,
             Col2,
             Col3)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
FROM   __MigrationHistory
```

Also, sp_rename is a SQL Server Stored Procedure. An equivalent in MySQL is [`RENAME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rename-table.html). In your case, this will probably work:

```
RENAME TABLE TempMigrationHistory TO __MigrationHistory;
```

Comment: thanks the prob is that that the tempmigrationhistory table doesnt exist - so I thought it would need to create an in memory table and then move it ? the issue is that using EF 4.3 - creates a system table that I need not to be a system table ?

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to address the specific issue you are encountering. As written, your question seems to ask how to insert records and rename a table. The system table issue came out of left field.